# Vue 2: Using router-link, but button stays on page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, routerlink

I'm pretty new to Vue 2 and I'm struggling with my router-link. So, in my parent component, I have a button to create a post that when a user clicks on it, they are redirected to a Create Post form. However upon redirecting, the button is still visible in the Create Post form.  How can I fix this or can anyone point me to the right direction?

App.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
     <router-link to="/post/create" exact>
      <button type="button">Create Post</button>
     // this button is visible in my CreatePost component when I need it to not be
     </router-link>
     <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>
```

routes/index.js

```
(...)
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router ({
  routes:[
    {
      path: '/post/create',
      name: 'CreatePost',
      component: CreatePost // this component is imported 
    }  

  ]

})
```

Comment: It shouldn't be in `App.vue` so, but in a page nested so that it can be displayed/hidden via the `router-view`. If you put it above the `router-view`, it will be everywhere indeed.

Comment: An additional layer may be needed, like `App/default layout/CreatePost` kind of structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view)-

> router-view will display the component that corresponds to the URL.
> You can put it anywhere to adapt it to your layout.

As per the above definition, your button is in the same file where your `router-view` is. That means every route's component will render where `<router-view>` is and so does would have the button at the top.

So, a solution would be-

1. Create a home route that will render a `Home.vue` component and put your `<router-link>` there.
2. In `App.vue`, leave only `router-view`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. That makes sense, it's similar to how when starting up a vue project and it has the Hello World component routed to '/', I can just put a component holding my button there. Thank you so much!